# Browser reload Tab close differentiate calling events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Browser reload is calling Unload event only and tab close is also calling Unload event, is there any difference or order of calling events to control ….??

Comment: Javascript or Jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery unload event only for close window not for Link navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565235/jquery-unload-event-only-for-close-window-not-for-link-navigation)

Comment: Sorry CBroe, It is not working for all scenarios…
Browser had different events for every action, those are Reload button, Tab close button and F5 key and body click events. To understand high-level   I need browser events list for every action before execution so that I can handle event by order.